# Illustrator: How to merge to circles and rectangle in illustrator from this sketch to make a blob?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

How to merge to circles and rectangle in illustrator from this sketch to make a blob?

[image]

Now I'm trying to get this logo (using these shapes). Should I use the Metaball tool to create the one shape or another way?

[image]

Trying to get this shape happening (see left)

[image]

Comment: Is my answer what you're looking for? If not, please explain your desired effect in more detail.

Comment: @Johannes Hey, Johannes this isn't quite what I'm after although I did it with circles and manually selecting and creating anchor points to delete sections of the circle.

Comment: As an aside...if you're making this for a logo, note the somewhat related [Nickelodeon splat](http://wac.450f.edgecastcdn.net/80450F/wgrd.com/files/2012/10/nickelodeon-logo.jpg).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this?

[image: metaball script]

If so then this should do the trick: http://shspage.com/aijs/en/#metaball

[image: metaballing technique]

Note that you might want to play with the metaball parameter and interior circle size to get a smoother curve on the ends.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm after. Now to make it look the way I want.

Comment: You seem to be getting it pretty close on your own. Probably some combination of techniques displayed in this thread will be needed to get you exactly what you want.

Answer (score 12):

This is actually something which the **Shape Builder Tool** makes very easy and you can use the circle configuration you already have....

[image]

**Without** the need to draw any more paths.

- Simply select the circles and grab the **Shape Builder Tool**
- Click and drag on the areas you wish to **combine**.
- To **remove** an area hold the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key and click-drag.

This makes it a matter of seconds to get from the circle configuration to the desired end shape.

[image: blob]

**Note:** This assumes the original circle configuration has the circles *actually touching* one another. If there's a slight gap between circles it may result in uneven curves in the final shape.

Comment: Nice manual solution. TIL.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this from within illustrator using the [pathfinder](http://www.bittbox.com/illustrator/pathfinder-explained) tool:

Just draw out your shapes, select them, and `unite` them.
[image]

Another example:
[image]